# Confused about bash behaviour - Bash / awk mystery

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, ubuntu-15.10

Why I get this output while using the Bash shell? I don't understand because if I run the command directly I always get the same input (":0")

```
oneUser $ w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3}'
:0
oneUser $ w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3}'
:0
oneUser $ w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3}'
:0
```

But then:

```
oneUser $ TEST=$(w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3}')
oneUser $ echo $TEST

oneUser $ TEST=$(w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3}')
oneUser $ echo $TEST

oneUser $ TEST=$(w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3}')
oneUser $ echo $TEST
:0
oneUser $ TEST=$(w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3}')
oneUser $ echo $TEST

oneUser $ TEST=$(w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3}')
oneUser $ echo $TEST

oneUser $ TEST=$(w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3}')
oneUser $ echo $TEST

oneUser $ TEST=$(w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3}')
oneUser $ echo $TEST
:0
```

Edit 1: Output of "w -h oneUser"

```
oneUser  :0       :0               08:37   ?xdm?  20:23   0.17s /sbin/upstart --user
oneUser  pts/5    :0               08:51    0.00s  1.73s  0.00s w -h oneUser
```

Edit 2: Printing $0 as well:

```
oneUser $ TEST=$(w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $0,$3}')
oneUser $ echo $TEST

oneUser $ TEST=$(w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $0,$3}')
oneUser $ echo $TEST
oneUser pts/5 :0 08:51 1.00s 1.82s 0.00s awk /w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $0,$3} :0
```

Edit 3: I found that sometimes:

```
oneUser $ w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3,$0}'
:0 oneUser  pts/5    :0               08:51    2.00s  1.97s  0.00s w -h oneUser
oneUser $ w -h oneUser | awk '/w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3,$0}'
:0 oneUser  pts/5    :0               08:51    3.00s  1.97s  0.00s awk /w -h/ {if($3 ~ /^:/) print $3,$0}
```

Comment: What's the output from `w -h oneUser`

Comment: Can you show what `w -h oneUser` outputs on your machine?

Comment: Try putting `print $0,$3` in the awk and show the output on one of the cases where $3 is blank.

Answer (score 1):

From the manpage of the *w(1)* on my machine:

> The w utility prints a summary of the current activity on the system,
>   including what each user is doing.

When you build a pipe like `w -h oneUser | awk`, you are doing two things: running `w` an running `awk`.  Your experiment demonstrate that on your system, the output of `w` examining a user running a complex command is not deterministic and can display any part of the pipe as “the current activity”.  Change your *awk* script to add some debugging demonstration to gain a better understanding about this.

Comment: Ok, I printed $0 as well